# Developing Geoserver Extension

Tags: geoserver, extensions

I want to develop geoserver extension that intercepts wms request, checks specific url parameter, builds clusters of points and generate the response image with clusters.

I've studied a little the geoserver code. And I'm planning now to replace "FeatureLayer" in "mapContent" by my class. The class replaces real points by clusters of points.

The problem is I don't know how to inject my extension code into wms processing.

Comment: It's all [here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src). Enjoy :D Failing that, it might be easier to do client side, say with OpenLayers clustering, and use Geoserver to generate based on WMS parameters you send.

Comment: Where is "here"? It's geoserver source. I see. Can you specify more exact? Client side clustering cannot be used with more than 600 points because of perfomance.

Comment: In the folder called WMS. The point being, if you want to create a plugin for Geoserver, you will need to understand the source code. This is why I suggested doing this client side, using cluster strategy, and calling your wms with appropriate layers to build up the image you want.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, though. If you could explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to build clusters of points like in a openlayers client and generate image of map with these clusters.

Comment: Not sure if you can solve this writing your own [Rendering Transformation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html) that would be expressed in the layer SLD. I'm not sure because I'm afraid you cannot access vendor parameters at that point.

Comment: You could also use the PointStacker in sld.

Very detailed explanation and example here : https://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/cartography/rt/pointstacker.html

Also the gs:PointStacker enables GetFeatureInfo as opposed to vec:PointStacker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have eclipse workspace as it shown in Geoserver Developers Quick Start.

Create new java project. Create new class:

```
package org.geoserver.wms.cluster;

import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallback;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallbackAdapter;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapRequest;
import org.geoserver.wms.WMSMapContent;

public class ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter extends GetMapCallbackAdapter
        implements GetMapCallback {

    public ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter() {
    }
    @Override
    public GetMapRequest initRequest(GetMapRequest request) {       
        return request;
    }
    @Override
    public void initMapContent(WMSMapContent mapContent) {    
    }
    @Override
    public WMSMapContent beforeRender(WMSMapContent mapContent) {
        return mapContent;
    }
}
```

Add file applicationContext.xml to META-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="getMapCallback" class="org.geoserver.wms.cluster.ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Append new project to the dependencies of "gs-wms" project.
Build solution. Set breakpoints at your code. Start geoserver. Create WMS layer. Browse to GetMap request. See breakpoints hitting.